# Rotate bitmap image around a center : Android

Tags: android

Can we rotate a bitmap image around a center. i am crruntly using a code but it rotates around it self

```
public Bitmap rotateCar(Bitmap carImage,float degrees)
{
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(degrees);

    Bitmap rotatedCarImage=Bitmap.createBitmap(carImage,0,0, carImage.getWidth(), carImage.getHeight(),matrix, true);
     return rotatedCarImage;
}//end of rotate car
```

Comment: There's an answer to a similar question [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182861/android-rotation-of-image-around-the-center?rq=1

Comment: These solutions are not clear. i want to make a distance from a center and rotate image around it.

Comment: i want to rotate a object around a center making some radius from center